# How Do Texture Coordinates Work When They Aren't Correctly Assigned?

Tags: opengl, opengl-3

Let's assume we have a texture like this

[image: 1]

and an array of vertices like this:

```
float vertices[]{
        //Pos           //TexCoor
        0  ,  0,        1,0,
        0.5,  0,        1,0,
        0.5,  0.5,      1,1,

        0  ,  0,        0,0,
        0.5,  0.5,      1,1,
        0  ,  0.5,      0,1,
    };
```

If textures coordinates represent a point on a texture which is then stretched on to the triangle, the mapping should look like this:

[image: this]

where red arrows represent the mappings to the 1st triangle and the purple ones to the 2nd.

Yet when I run the program I get a result like

[image: this]

where there isn't any red even though 2 vertices are mapped to the red corner of the texture.

Comment: Which wrap mode is set? I ask because when the wrap mode is set to repeat, then the a value of exactly 1 on a texture coordinate is wrapped to `1 mod 1 = 0`. The whole image looks as expected when you substitute 1 with 0 for texCoord.x for the bottom-right triangle. (and is noticeable because all texels there have an exact x value of 1 after interpolation.

Comment: @BDL It was set to repeat. Everything worked as I expected when I set it to clamp. Thank you so much!